# How to get an union in a structure working in C

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, union

I have an assignment where I need to represent the following data as output:

- average CO2 value
- amount of incorrect readings
- average CO2 value from 1958 till 1968
- average CO2 value from 2008 till 2018
- maximum CO2 value and the year and month it was measured
- minimum CO2 value and the year and month it was measured

I have coded the following program, where I declare a structure, initialize the structure and print the values of the structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Represents statistics of a CO2 table.
struct Statistics {
    double co2_average_total;
    int amount_of_incorrect_data;
    double co2_average_1958_1968;
    double co2_average_2008_2018;


    union Co2_MIN {
      double co2_value;
      int month;
      int year;
    };

    union Co2_MAX {
      double co2_value;
      int month;
      int year;
    };
};

typedef struct Statistics Statistics;

// initializes statistics
Statistics make_statistics(void) {
    Statistics st;
    union Co2_MIN co2_MIN;
    union Co2_MAX co2_MAX;

    st.co2_average_total = 0.00;
    st.amount_of_incorrect_data = 0;
    st.co2_average_1958_1968 = 0.00;
    st.co2_average_2008_2018 = 0.00;

    st.co2_MIN.co2_value = 500.00;
    st.co2_MIN.month = 0;
    st.co2_MIN.year = 0;

    st.co2_MAX.co2_value = 0.00;
    st.co2_MAX.month = 0;
    st.co2_MAX.year = 0;


    return st;
}

// prints statistics
void print_statistics(Statistics s) {
    printf("\nmean CO2:\t\t\t%.2f", s.co2_average_total); // average co2
    printf("\nnumber errors:\t\t\t%d", s.amount_of_incorrect_data); // number of errors
    printf("\nmean CO2 in 1958 - 1968:\t\t\t%.2f", s.co2_average_1958_1968); // average co2 1958-1968
    printf("\nmean CO2 in 2008 - 2018:\t\t\t%.2f", s.co2_average_2008_2018);    // average co2 2008-2018
    printf("\nMinimum CO2 of %2.f was measured in %i.%i", s.co2_MIN.co2_value, s.co2_MIN.month, s.co2_MIN.year);    // minimum of Co2 value measured on month,year
    printf("\nMaximum CO2 of %2.f was measured in %i.%i", s.co2_MAX.co2_value, s.co2_MAX.month, s.co2_MAX.year); // maximum of co2 value measured on month,year
}


int main() {

    Statistics s = make_statistics();
    print_statistics(s);

    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile the program I get the message:

```
error: 'Statistics {aka struct Statistics}' has no member named 'co2_MIN'
```

So apparently I declared my unions wrong at the start of my code.
I have however no idea what exactly I did wrong.
Could you please help me debug my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on how you are given the input data, the tricky part here is likely to be handling the data.  Think about how you're going to model not just the end result, but the data you'll be given, and how to iterate over it to update a `Statistics`.  Also, C is case sensitive, like nearly everything else so fix the `co2_` or the `Co2_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the `union` tags inside the struct. Move them out and declare them at the top of the translation unit (file), then add them as fields of the `Statistics` struct.

```
union Co2_MAX {
  double co2_value;
  int month;
  int year;
};

union Co2_MIN {
  double co2_value;
  int month;
  int year;
};

struct Statistics {
    double co2_average_total;
    int amount_of_incorrect_data;
    double co2_average_1958_1968;
    double co2_average_2008_2018;

    union Co2_MAX co2_max;
    union Co2_MIN co2_min;
};
```

Though I am unsure whether an `union` is a correct data structure for the job, since in the original post you state that you need to store:

> - maximum CO2 value and the year and month it was measured
> - minimum CO2 value and the year and month it was measured

An `union` can only store at most one of its fields at a time (either the value, month, or year based on your example).

Comment: no point in having a different type for min and max.  They should be the same type and yes, I'd agree, a `struct`, not a `union`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are right, unions are not the best for this job. I implemented your code but replaced union with structures.